# Как создать классы в рабочем коде?

Tags: классы, c++

Добрый день!

Есть задача, которую надо решить через классы. Не смогла разобраться толком с ними, с созданием файла .h и в общем. Решила как смогла, ибо завтра сдавать дз, код рабочий, но можно ли как-то исправить его чтобы были соблюдены описанные требования к классам? Описание задачи может быть неточным (в переводе).

---

α) Написать программу, которая будет использовать класс Rectangular с данными прямоугольника. Переменные width и height содержат данные сторон прямоугольника и принадлежат классу.

Написать
α) constructor который не принимает аргументов
β) constructorкоторый принимает 2 аргумента
γ) setWidth, setHeight которые принимают две стороны прямоугольника
δ) getWidth, getHeight которые возвращают две стороны прямоугольника
ε) getArea которое считает площадь
στ) getPerimeter которое считает периметр

Далее написать код, который работает на два прямоугольника (10,7) и (10,12). Данные первого заданы изначально, второго – задаются setWidth и setHeight. Результат – вывод на экран их площадей

β) Написать класс квадрат Square, является расширением класса rectangle. Написать constructor который будет получать значение стороны квадрата.

Далее программа должна работать для квадратов со сторонами 10 и 7. Также выводить их площадь и периметр.

γ) Добавить класс Box- куб и constructor, который будет получать три параметра куба (длину, высоту, ширину)
getVolume и getArea используются из родительского класса. scale(double f) умножает параметры (размеры) куба на f.
В программе – 2 куба (10,10,10) и (7,8,3).
На экран выводится объем куба, площади его поверхностей. Затем вызывается scale – коэффициенты 0,5 и 2. На экран выводятся новые данные.

Итог: 1 программа с 1 main, 3 .cpp и 3 .h (1 на каждый класс (rectangle, squre, box))

---

а вот и сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class percalc
{
  public:
  void per(int a);
  void per(int a,int b);
};

void percalc::per(int a)
{
    cout<<"\n  Perimetr of Square ="<<(4*a);
}

void percalc::per(int a, int b)
{
     cout<<"\n  Perimetr of Rectangle="<<((a+b)*2);
}

class areacalc
{
  public:
  void area(int a);
  void area(int a,int b);
  void area(int a,int b,int d);
};

void areacalc::area(int a)
{
    cout<<"\n  Area of Square="<<(a*a);
}

void areacalc::area(int a,int b)
{
    cout<<"\n  Area of Rectangle="<<(a*b);
}

void volume (int a,int b,int c)
{
    cout<<"\n  Volume of box="<<a*b*c;
}

void area (int a, int b, int c)
{
    cout<<"\n  Area of the first side of box="<<a*b;
    cout<<"\n  Area of the second side of box="<<a*c;
    cout<<"\n  Area of the third side of box="<<c*b;
    cout<<"\n  Area of all sides of box="<<2*a*b+2*a*c+2*b*c;
}

void scale (int a,int b, int c, float sc)
{
    area (a*sc, b*sc, c*sc);
    volume (a*sc, b*sc, c*sc);
}

main()
{
   areacalc ac;
   percalc pc;
   cout<<"Rectangle with sides 10 and 7"<<endl;
   ac.area(10,7);
   pc.per (10,7);
   cout<<"\n\n\nRectangle with sides 10 and 12"<<endl;
   ac.area(10,12);
   pc.per (10,12);
   cout<<"\n\n\n\nSquare with side 10"<<endl;
   ac.area(10);
   pc.per (10);
   cout<<"\n\n\nSquare with side 7"<<endl;
   ac.area(7);
   pc.per (7);
   cout<<"\n\n\n\nCube with side 10"<<endl;
   area (10,10,10);
   volume(10,10,10);
   cout<<"\n\n\n\nScale 0,5"<<endl;
   scale (10,10,10,0.5);
   cout<<"\n\n\n\nScale 2"<<endl;
   scale (10,10,10,2);
   cout<<"\n\n\nBox with sides 7, 8 and 3"<<endl;
   area (7,8,3);
   volume(7,8,3);
   cout<<"\n\n\nScale 0,5"<<endl;
   scale (7,8,3,0.5);
   cout<<"\n\n\nScale 2"<<endl;
   scale (7,8,3,2);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что этот ваш код никакого отношения к этому заданию не имеет, и вы добавили его здесь, только для того, что-бы как-то обойти правила форума :P

Comment: @Mary Ustyantseva: А что конкретно не нравится компилятору в header-файлах? Выложите код и сообщение об ошибке, а также к какой строке оно относится.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не забыли класс Rectangular?
Все функции, которые вы написали, вполне могут быть статическими, так как не используют закрытых полей классов, не говоря уже о том, что полей вообще никаких нет.

На будущее, классы в файлах располагаются примерно так:

```
// some_type.h
//=====================

/*
С помощью деректив препроцессора необходимо обезопаситься от
повторного включения объявления класса. Например, когда
type1.h инклудится в type2.h, а потом нам будет необходимо
заинклудить type1 и type2 в одном файле (по тем или иным причинам).
Выходит, что type1 будет включен дважды (явно и не явно через type2).
*/

#ifndef __SOME_TYPE_H__ 
#define __SOME_TYPE_H__

class SomeType
{
    int memberVar_; // закрытое поле

public:  
    SomeType(int value);

    // Геттеры и сеттеры для доступа к закрытому полю
    int getValue() const { return memberVar_; }
    void setValue(int value) { memberVar_ = value; }

    void someMemberFunction();
};

#endif // __SOME_TYPE_H__

//=====================
// some_type.cpp
//=====================

#include "some_type.h"

SomeType::SomeType(int value)
    : memberVar_(value)
{
    // ... тело конструктора
}

void SomeType::someMemberFunction()
{
    //... тело метода
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прототипы классов, код ф-й дописать я думаю не составит труда, если конечно вы писали приведенный выше код сами :))):

```
// Rectangular.h
class Rectangular {
protected:
    double width;
    double height; 
public:
    Rectangular();
    Rectangular(double height, double width);
    void setWidth(double width);
    void setHeight(double height);
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter();
};
// Square.h
class Square: public Rectangular {
public:
    Square(double side);
};
// Box.h
class Box: public Rectangular {
protected:
    double depth;
public:
    Box(double width, double height, double depth);
    double getVolume();
    double getArea();
    void scale(double f);
}
```

Comment: Код сама писала, но при создании классов в .h файлах компилятор ругается.
Где-то допускаю ошибку и не понимаю где :(

Comment: Создайте somename.h поместите определения классов в него, сами реализации ф-й поместите в somename.cpp, вначале которого заинклудьте somename.h
И приведите, если возможно ошибки, которые выдает компилятор